# How should I format this mock JS data so I can use it after a get request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an input field that collects an ID and should use that ID to find the corresponding entry. Below is what I currently have and at the bottom is what I would like to have.

I can get the contents of the file, but I can't do anything with it.

What I currently have:

```
// mock-data.js
{
  id: "239491",
  name: "Big Bird",
  real: false,
  type: "Animal"
}
```

And in my Vue file I'm using `axios` for my `GET` call

```
// search-file.Vue
axios.get('static/mock-data.js')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

This logs out what appears to be a giant string, because there's no syntax highlighting in the console.

What I would like to have is something like:

```
{
  entries: [
    "239491": {
      id: "239491",
      name: "Big Bird",
      real: false,
      type: "Animal"
    },
    "983502": {
      id: "983502",
      name: "Frodo",
      real: false,
      type: "Hobbit"
    },
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

And my Vue code would ideally be something like:

```
axios.get('static/mock-data/entries/' + userInput)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

I know this isn't the proper syntax, but I can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create a data for test purpose or none blocking front end development, why don't you call it directly? What I would do is f

```js
function mockDataService() {
  var mockData = {
    entries: [
      "239491": {
        id: "239491",
        name: "Big Bird",
        real: false,
        type: "Animal"
      },
      "983502": {
        id: "983502",
        name: "Frodo",
        real: false,
        type: "Hobbit"
      }
    ]
  };
  return {
    getMockDataById: function(id) {
      //return mock data by id
    }
  }
}


//you can mock out axios or just create a fake promise.
function callMockData(userInput) {
  return {
    then: function(success, failure) {
      success(mockDataService.getMockDataById(userInput))
    }
  }
}
```